# Link unresponsive in Salesforce1, is target attribute to blame?

Tags: salesforce1-app, mobile, outputlink, windows8

I have the following in a page in an S1 app:

```
<apex:outputLink value="/apex/temp_pageTwo" target="_parent">

</apex:outputLink>
```

In my browser and on Android and iPhone, it works fine.

But the link is comletely unresponsive on a Windows Phone. It won't work at all.

If I remove the target attribute, it works fine...

```
<apex:outputLink value="/apex/temp_pageTwo">

</apex:outputLink>
```

Could anyone possibly tell me why this is??

In S1, there can be only one tab, so could the target attribute be of any real use here at all?

I can't seem to figure it out...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is correct, the browser on Windows Phone does not support `target` attribute for any hyperlinks.  The `<apex:outputLink>` is treated similar to a `<href>` and it is not supported on Windows Phone.

This has been confirmed by a Microsoft employee on this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12201436/how-to-open-a-new-window-or-tab-via-javascript-in-windows-phone-7-browser).